# Wordpress Failed to load resource

Tags: wordpress, permissions

I'm having weird issues after installing WordPress, (using a subdomain and separate directory) it seems that files are not loading properly.

1. Freshly installed WordPress
2. Using the default theme
3. No https thing

I did contact the host support about this (I did assume that it's a permission issue) and he even temporarily set the directory permission to 777 and files to 666 to see if that resolves the issue. but unfortunately, it didn't. We tried everything already still doesn't work! I'm stuck

[image]

Comment: Does your site use https? it could be a "mixed content" issue

Comment: no it doesn't. it's really wierd.

Comment: Press F12 and look at the log at the bottom right corner. You could find a clue there.

Comment: what do you mean log? i'm looking at the console right now and it's saying that "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" on some js,css and fonts files.

Comment: @JeremiLiwanag Can you make a screenshot of your console, and added it to you post? Also do you have an htaccess in the root of your project?

Comment: This sometime happens if the siteurl is not correct. check it's values. tell us what the domain is and what url shows up for missing images when you inspect them.

Comment: @JeremiLiwanag, please add a screenshot of your console. Additionally, confirm that in your database `wp_options` table the **site_url** & **home** both have the correct URL value. Did you install any SSL certificate?

Comment: Go to permalinks in dashboard and without changing anything just press the save button. In the wordpress directory you should have an .htaccess. Compare it to the .htaccess in the subdomain root folder. If they are different post them masking if there is any sensitive data. Also check if the index.php in the subdomain root folder is rewritting to the wordpress folder. (This is assuming that the url you enter takes you to the subdomain folder right.)

Comment: @JeremiLiwanag if you are using  your subdomain  **site url & home url**  without www try using it with www or www is already there then remove and try

Answer (score 0):

If i understand properly, your js & css files are not loading. correct?
check your js & css file path in inspect. its proper or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading your files, make sure your folders are appropriately named according to your code and linking between pages/folders.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

[Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-not-found-8/)

I think the folders path is not correct.check once your files path and reload. Check once your CSS and JS path names also then again reload the page